# Inputstream failed to connect to a URL

Tags: android

I am getiing a xml content of a page and parsing some URL from that xml which are all images Url.
Then I am making the image to be shown in imageviwer using bitmap. Further I need that image for my next layout design. How can I store the images for further use, can I store the images in drawable folder if I can how to do it. I have mentioned below in the code where I need to save the imageview content to drawable folder..

```
         protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

                     try {
                         url=new URL(UrlLink2) ;
                         urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                            InputStream isp=urlConnection.getInputStream();
                        DocumentBuilderFactory DBF=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        DocumentBuilder Db=DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
                            doc=Db.parse(isp);
                            Element rootElem=doc.getDocumentElement();
                            NodeList itemlist=rootElem.getElementsByTagName("item");
                            Node currentitem=null;
                            Node childnode=null;
                            Node ContentChild=null;
                            Node CddatatChild=null;
                            NodeList childnodeList=null;
                            NodeList CddataList=null;
                            NodeList ContentChilList=null;
                            for(int i=0;i<itemlist.getLength();i++){
                                currentitem=itemlist.item(i);
                                childnodeList=currentitem.getChildNodes();
                                for(int j=0;j<childnodeList.getLength();j++){
                                    childnode=childnodeList.item(j);
                                    if(childnode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")){
                                        ContentChilList=childnode.getChildNodes();
                                        ContentChilList.getLength();
                                        CddatatChild=ContentChilList.item(0);
                                        CddataList=CddatatChild.getChildNodes();
                                            if(CddatatChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("#cdata-section")){
                                                GetCddata=CddatatChild.getTextContent().toString();
                                                    GetCddata=CddatatChild.getTextContent();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                    catch(Exception e){

                    }
                     try{
                         int i=0;                
                          String ss=GetCddata;
                 Pattern PatternImgURLS = Pattern.compile("(?<=a href=\")(.*?)(?=\")");
                 Pattern PatternImgname = Pattern.compile("(?<=2014\\/09\\/)(.*?)(?=\\.)");
                 Matcher Imagematcher = PatternImgURLS.matcher(ss);    
                 Imagematcher.matches();
                 while (Imagematcher.find()) {
                      ImgUrl=Imagematcher.toMatchResult().group();
                         ImageUrls.add(ImgUrl); 
                        i++;    
                    } 
                 for(int count=0;count<ImageUrls.size();count++){
                     Matcher Namematcher = PatternImgname.matcher(ImageUrls.get(count));
                     Namematcher.matches(); 
                     while (Namematcher.find()) {
                     String MatchTxt=Namematcher.toMatchResult().group();
                     String lowerMatchTxt = MatchTxt.toLowerCase();
                     ImageName.add(lowerMatchTxt);
                     Log.v("dd",ImageName.get(count)); 
                        }
                     }
                       Log.v("dd",ImageUrls.get(0)); 
                       int t=ImageUrls.size();    
                       Log.v("dd",toString().valueOf(t)); 
                       urlConnection.disconnect();
                       url=new URL(ImageUrls[0]) ;
                       urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                       urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                       InputStream isp2=urlConnection.getInputStream();
                       bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(isp2);
                       urlConnection.disconnect();
                     }
                     catch(Exception e){
                              Log.v("h",e.toString()) ;  }

                             @Override        
          protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                          super.onPostExecute(result);
                          dialog.dismiss();
 Here I am displaying---> Imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 the image in Image viwer       
Now how do I store the image from the imageviewer to 
drawable folder in andriod is that possiable.  
       }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to implement it by yourself, but take well known library that can do it for you. For instance, [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) has features that should suit your needs. You just pass an URL to it and Picasso will download and save an image in a cache folder for next use:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

All you have to do is to parse those image URLs and store them somewhere in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store/write to res/drawable during run time.But you can change your program to use alternate forms of storage refer this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot save youur images in res/drawable because once the .apk file has been deployed, the resources cannot change.

But you can use cache directory of your application. It's a non-public folder which belongs to your application and will be deleted on uninstall. furthermore the system can delete from this directory for you if the device is running short of space. It can be accessed via :

```
context.getCacheDir()
```

Note though that the docs say:

**you should not rely on the system deleting these files for you; you should always have a       reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files when exceeding that space**

If you need a lot of space and would rather use the SD card you can call

```
 getExternalCacheDir()
```

instead. These will also get removed on uninstall, but the system does not monitor the space available in external storage, so won't automatically delete these files if low on space. If using this option you should also check that external storage is available with

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState()
```

Environment.getExternalStorageState()
before attempting to write to it.